# I have got 'on hold'

Tags: support

I have got `[on hold]` on https://askubuntu.com/questions/596424/how-to-write-a-auto-completion-bash-script

What should I do now?

Answer (score 5):

It was put on hold because you posted the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Since the U&L question is still alive and has been answered, you needn't do anything for this post. In future, please do not post the same question on multiple SE sites.

Comment: What if I try to edit the post? It says so.

Comment: @VinuKevy unless you significantly change the question, it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

It's closed because you have an answer on another site and you crossposted on 3 different sites.  We talked about this earlier in chat.  That's a no-no.  Since there's already an answer or partial answer on UL, that is the ONLY one that should remain open as opposed to closed/on-hold.